# How to observe added events in Meteor without firing on initialization?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

There is a lot of information on this topic out there, but I can't seem to get it working for myself. I am using toastr to display notifications of events to the user in the top right hand corner of my app. I need to add an observer for the 'added' event to a collection, and create the toastr notification when an item is added. The problem is that the observer fires when the collection is initialized. I've tried about a half dozen different ways trying to check of the collection is ready() before I allow the observer code to continue through and show notifications, but I can't get it working consistently, especially when changing pages. Here is some sample code:

```
MainController = RouteController.extend({
    before: [
        function() {
            deviceEventsInitializing = true;
            var alerts = this.subscribe("alerts", Meteor.user()._id);
            if (alerts.ready()) {
                deviceEventsInitializing = false;
            }
            Alerts.find().observeChanges({
                added: function(id, doc) {
                    if (deviceEventsInitializing || deviceEventsInitializing == undefined) {
                        return;
                    }
                    doToastrStuff();
                }
            });
            this.next();
        }
    ],
});
```

This is just my latest attempt. The flow goes like this:

1.) Subscription happens, all the items in the collection hit the observer but deviceEventsInitializing is true so it does nothing.
2.) alerts.ready() fires and deviceEventsInitilizing is set to false.
3.) The added trigger fires again for all the events in the collection, causing toastr to be called for every item.

All I'm interested in is the following:

1.) Some trigger or event where I can set a variable that says the subscription is reloading the collection.
2.) Some trigger or event that tells me that this reloading of the collection is complete so I can set a variable indicating that.

Comment: I don't have an answer but a suggestion - you might greatly simplify the task by setting up your observeChanges outside of the router. Iron Router before() hooks are designed to run multiple times as data changes so even if you change a flag from true to false, the hook might run again from the top with the flag set to true. It may work to do the observe from a Meteor.startup

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track, but trying to manage reactivity like this using solely IronRouter can be a nightmare. I've tried and failed before.

Instead, leverage Mongo to limit your reactivity to only alerts you care about. Let's imagine your `alerts` database looks something like:

```js
{
  _id: 1,
  hasNotified: false,
  ...
}
```

Now, Mongo is deciding what is new vs. not new instead of trying to determine state based on IronRouter timing. In fact, because in Meteor any `alerts` cursor is natively reactive, you don't even need to `observeChanges`:

```js
MainController = RouteController.extend({
  waitOn: function() {
    return this.subscribe("alerts", Meteor.userId());
  },
  data: function() {
    var newAlerts = Alerts.find({hasNotified: false}).forEach(function(doc) {
      doToastrStuff();
      Alerts.update({_id: doc._id}, {$set: {hasNotified: true}});
    });
  }
})
```

With this kind architecture, navigating to other routes, reloading the page, etc. will not re-fire any of your alerts because Mongo stores your alert state.